# Validating JSON schema in Postman

Tags: postman, ajv, tv4, postman-testcase

When using Postman I validate the JSON response like so:

```
tv4.addSchema(globalSchema);                
const valResult = tv4.validate(data, schema);

// schema is an object, which is a subschema from the larger globalSchema
```

which works fine, except for the error reporting. The error object I get is missing `dataPath` and `schemaPath`, making it hard for my user to find out where the actual problem is. Is there a way to get those properties? (tried validateResult and validateMultiple to no avail)

As an alternative I tried ajv, but as I am in draft-04, it gives me errors. The advice from their site

```
var ajv = new Ajv({schemaId: 'id'});
// If you want to use both draft-04 and draft-06/07 schemas:
// var ajv = new Ajv({schemaId: 'auto'});
ajv.addMetaSchema(require('ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-04.json'));
```

does not work because the Postman sandbox does not allow me to require that… any thoughts?

See also: https://community.getpostman.com/t/json-schema-validation-troubles/5024

Comment: Thanks @Henke for looking into this. I'm no longer with this project, so I can't tell if it helps, but from the looks of things, the suggestion you're making does not allow for using draft-04 in ajv?

Comment: Yes, I now think you are right and that I was wrong flagging it as a possible duplicate. My apologies. . . . (I removed my comment and retracted the flag.) . . .
Possibly relevant - https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/895? https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv#user-content-using-version-7? https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/904?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I validate schema's with postman to get more detailed errors:

```
const schema = {
};

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test('Checking Response Against Schema Validation', function() {
    var result=tv4.validateMultiple(jsonData, schema);
    console.log(result);
    pm.expect(result.valid).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: And you do get the dataPath and schemaPath members? Could you provide an example of your log?

Comment: It'll throw a complete list of all the errors. However, it doesn't specify which fields failed, So this might be less useful for you than I originally thought.

Sample from console:
`errors:
0:
message:"String does not match pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}"
name:"ValidationError"
type:"Error"
1:
message:"String does not match pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}"
name:"ValidationError"
type:"Error"`
...

Comment: That's why my original question said: "The error object I get is missing dataPath and schemaPath, making it hard for my user to find out where the actual problem is. Is there a way to get those properties?" Thanks for trying to help me out though.